# Error in testing the properties of object using jest with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

It's my first time to write tests. I'm writing tests for a ReactJS app wrote with hooks, and testing using [Jest](https://jestjs.io) and [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library).

I have trouble when I test object will render multiple times on its all properties.

Here's the functional component:

```
const ItemDetails = ({ item }) => {
  const { code } = item;
  const { getBarcode } = useStationContext();

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          getBarcode(code);
        }}
      >
        Print Barcode
      </Button>
      <List
        dataSource={formatData(item)}
        renderItem={({ title, value }) => (
          <List.Item>
            <List.Item.Meta
              description={
                <Wrapper>
                  <p>{upperCase(title)}</p>
                  <div data-testid="itmVal">{value}</div>
                </Wrapper>
              }
            />
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ItemDetails;
```

Here's the test file:

```
beforeEach(cleanup);

describe('itemDetails()', () => {
  test('Return Details about item', () => {
    const { getByText, getByTestId, container, asFragment, debug } = render(
      <StationProvider>
        <ItemDetails
          item={{
            id: '296-c-4f-89-18',
            barcode: 'E-6',
          }}
        />
      </StationProvider>,
    );

    expect(getByTestId('itmVal')).toHaveTextContent(
      '296-c-4f-89-18',
    );
    expect(getByTestId('itmVal')).toHaveTextContent('E-6');
  });
});
```

What actually happens, is in every time the test expected `296-c-4f-89-18` which is the first property of the object, so how can i fix this?

Comment: Could you provide us with a "working" example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) please? It would be useful to see it running on the client-side and breaking with the failing test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getBy`](https://testing-library.com/docs/api-queries#getby) functions in `react-testing-library` will always return the *first* matching item for your query - if you want to search for *all* matching items, you need to use the [`getAllBy`](https://testing-library.com/docs/api-queries#getallby) functions, which return an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by your code. In `ItemDetails` you are extracting the value `code` from `item`. But then in the test `item` hast the value `{ id: '296-c-4f-89-18', barcode: 'E-6' }`.

Anyway, it looks like you want to check that the two parameters you pass are rendered. I would use `getByText` in this case:

```
const { getByText } = render(
  <StationProvider>
    <ItemDetails
      item={{
        id: '296-c-4f-89-18',
        barcode: 'E-6',
      }}
    />
  </StationProvider>,
);

expect(getByText('296-c-4f-89-18')).toBeInTheDocument()
expect(getByText('E-6')).toBeInTheDocument()
```